# How to repair and prevent garage external shielding damage

Tags: walls, repair, insulation, garage, damage

We recently moved and I’m looking to insulate our garage. I noticed that a corner next to the garage door seems to have water/moisture damage but I’m not 100% sure.

It seems that the those 3 spots are the only parts suffering and crumbling. I’ve checked the rest of the garage and they’re fine from what I can tell.

How do I go about replacing this and preventing it from happening again? The exterior is vinyl siding and brick (front), but just vinyl on the sides.

[image]

[image]

[photos](https://imgur.com/a/3lfaqnv)

Comment: I'm not seeing signs of water damage.  It look more like damage from the previous owners stacking tools or something that damaged the walls.  Less likely is rodent damage.

Comment: @RMDman well that’s good news. Would you say it’s safe to insulate that portion without doing anything, or would it be appropriate to try to patch it up prior to insulation?

Comment: Patching would be prefered prior to insulating.

Comment: @RMDman Hey! So following up a bit. Would this be an appropriate temp fix/patch until spring time to replace the sheathing?

Piece of wood with 4mil sheeting stapled to it, maybe some spray foam around the edges to fully seal it. Thought I’d get another set of eyes before I decide to nail it in. 

[photo](https://imgur.com/a/8IgmP20)